# I have an Error when trying to compile lammps using 'make mpi'

Tags: libcurl, lammps

When I type 'make mpi' all the libraries are being compiled, but at the end this error msg is poping up.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sadgun/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[1]: *** [Makefile:94: ../lmp_mpi] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sadgun/lammps-23Jun2022/src/Obj_mpi'
make: *** [Makefile:393: mpi] Error 2
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.